# How can I alert the success message after I deleted all zero quantity on table using Angular?

Tags: angular

When I click the delete button it will delete all the products with zero quantity. I add an alert message to notify the user if the table has zero quantity or not. The success message will alert after deleting all the products with zero quantity and the error message alert if the table has no zero quantity. I'm using the *sweetalert2*. The problem is when I deleted all products that have zero quantity the error message showed instead of the success message. I want to show the success message after I deleted products and the error message only shows if the table has no zero quantity. How can I alert the success after I deleted all the products with zero quantity?

//Delete all the row with zero quantity

```
public onDeleteProduct(): void {
    this.productServive.deleteProduct().subscribe(
      (response: void) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.messageShow();
        this.getAllProduct();
        this.onCloseUpdateHandled();
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.errorMessage(error.message);
      }
    );
  }
```

// product quantity is zero or not

```
public messageShow(): void {
    for(const product of this.products) {
      if(product.quantity === 0) {
        this.successMessage("deleted");
      } else {
        this.errorMessage("No more out-of-stock");
      }
    }
  }
```

//html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" (click)="onDeleteProduct()">Delete</button>
```

//example table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggTL6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only print the errorMessage when you verified that no product has a quantity of 0. so it would be:

```
public messageShow(): void {
    for(const product of this.products) {
      if(product.quantity === 0) {
        this.successMessage("deleted");
        return;
      }
    }
    this.errorMessage("No more out-of-stock");
}
```

This method goes through all the products in the list. If it finds one with 0 quantity, it shows the success message and finishes the method (this is what the void return is used for). If it went through all products and has not find any with 0 quantity is shows the error message

Comment: same nothing changed

Comment: have you check the contents of this.products (with console.log) when messageShow() is called?

Comment: I try this one console.log(product.quantity); and on the console.log it's 0

Comment: see the edited answer to check if this is the problem

Comment: sir can you explain how it works?

Comment: I explained it better at the end of the answer. Let me know if there is anything you don't understand